# Value is coming back as Undefined

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables to display results on a table and then passing ID as URL parameter, we able to display details of a particular record to user.

So far, this works fine.

However, I have been asked to pass a second url parameter called user and this is presenting problems.

When I run the code, it is no longer displaying details page.

Upon reviewing the code using firebug, I found an error that says:

`john is undefined`.

john.doe is the value being displayed on the url that looks more like this:

```
http://mylink.com/viewDetails.php?ID=1235&userName=john.doe
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
return "<a target='tab' data-tab-name='#RequestDetails' data-tab-index='2' href='viewDetails.php?rID="
       + oObj.aData["ID"] + "&userName=" + <?php echo $user; ?> + "'> " + oObj.aData["ID"] + " </a>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like this after being parsed by PHP:

`<a target='tab' data-tab-name='#RequestDetails' data-tab-index='2' href='viewDetails.php?rID=" + oObj.aData["ID"] + "&userName=" + john + "'> " + oObj.aData["ID"] + " </a>`

That means it's looking for a variable called `john`, which as you can see is undefined.

It should be this:

`<a target='tab' data-tab-name='#RequestDetails' data-tab-index='2' href='viewDetails.php?rID=" + oObj.aData["ID"] + "&userName=<?php echo $user?>'> " + oObj.aData["ID"] + " </a>`

Comment: You got there before me +1

Comment: Yours is prettier though. +1.

Answer (score 3):

You need to but quotes around the php element as it is just going to write out the value of itself to the page. This way it becomes a string.

```
return "<a target='tab' data-tab-name='#RequestDetails' data-tab-index='2' href='viewDetails.php?rID="
       + oObj.aData["ID"] + "&userName=" + "<?php echo $user; ?>" + "'> " + oObj.aData["ID"] + " </a>";
```

Better put is this way...

```
return "<a target='tab' data-tab-name='#RequestDetails' data-tab-index='2' href='viewDetails.php?rID="
       + oObj.aData["ID"] + "&userName=<?php echo $user; ?>'> " + oObj.aData["ID"] + " </a>";
```