# Why am I still getting undefined error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

It turns out that I need to pass loginName as the first URL parameter and ID as second but still this JavaScript code below is not working.

```
 return "<a target='tab' data-tab-name='#RequestDetails' data-tab-index='2' href='viewDetails.php?loginName="
        + <?php echo $user; ?> + "&ID=" + oObj.aData["ID"] + "'> " + oObj.aData["ID"] + " </a>";
```

It is returning the same error I was having earlier.

We would like URL param with their values similar to this:

```
http://viewDetails.php?loginName="john.doe&ID=2984
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why all the `+` signs? I believe you're wanting to chain/concatenate these together with dots. Plus, remove the PHP tags. You're already in PHP, unless this is JS, which at this point seems unclear.

Comment: `"It is resturning same error I was having earlier."` - Would you care to share with us the error?  When you debug this, *what* is undefined?

Comment: -1, this is a [duplicate of your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087258/value-is-coming-back-as-undefined), and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24087304/472495) there looks good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your `$name` is a number, you're outputting what JavaScript thinks is a variable name - it's always important to look at the rendered result:

```
return "<a target='tab' data-tab-name='#RequestDetails' data-tab-index='2' href='viewDetails.php?loginName="
    + john.doe + "&ID=" + oObj.aData["ID"] + "'> " + oObj.aData["ID"] + " </a>";
//    ^^^^^^^^
```

See there? JavaScript is looking for an object called `john` with a `doe` property.

To pass a PHP variable into JavaScript, you use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-decode), like so:

```
return "<a target='tab' data-tab-name='#RequestDetails' data-tab-index='2' href='viewDetails.php?loginName="
    + <?php echo json_encode($user); ?> + "&ID=" + oObj.aData["ID"] + "'> " + oObj.aData["ID"] + " </a>";
```

That should probably work!

Comment: thank you very much. Thank you also Marc B. Thank you also Marc B.

Sorry to all for my poor question or slow up take.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that's a JS `return`, which means that:

```
 + <?php echo $user; ?> +
```

is going to produce something like:

```
var foo = "...." + name_of_user + "....";
```

and be see as an undefined variable. You probably want

```
var foo = "..." + <?php echo json_encode($user); ?> + "...";
```

which would produce

```
var foo = "..." + "name_of_user" + "...";
```

and be treated as a regular string.

Comment: Nitpick, but `json_encode` uses double-quotes around string values ;)

Comment: @xxcezz: if it was PHP code, then quoting the `<?php ... ?>` block would just make things worse. It's obviously JS code, and is probably being produced by a PHP script.

Comment: Just curious from either of you (for my knowledge). I noticed you both (@NiettheDarkAbsol as well) used `json_encode` for this scenario. Is it more appropriate to use `+ <?php json_encode($user); ?> +` rather than just dot concatenation `. $user . `? I figure there is a reason you both did it this way. Just not sure why.

Comment: @War10ck Context is important. This is a JavaScript context with PHP mixed in.

Comment: @war: it's a snippet of JS code, but almost certainly being produced by some PHP code. That means the PHP code is going to be outputting into a JS context, which means PHP has to produce syntactically valid JS code. `<?php json ?>` won't do anything, since it doesn't echo.

Comment: That makes sense. Good catch. I would have clearly missed that. Indeed context is important. :) Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol and _@MarcB_. +1 to you both. Learn something new everyday...